# Is it safe to send SIGTERM to JVM

Tags: java, scala, jvm, signals, shutdown-hook

Although JVM will [translate SIGTERM and similar signals to shutdown hooks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/signals.html), 
many service shutdown scripts use a TCP port to initiate a shutdown. (e.g. Tomcat's shutdown port, [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp), JBoss' management interfaces, etc.)

So I thought using signals and shutdown hooks to gracefully shutdown java services is discouraged, until I found that [Play! framework is managing the service lifecycle with shutdown hooks](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.1/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala) and the startup scripts generated by `play dist` assumes that a signal will be sent to the JVM's PID.

I know that signals are platform-dependent and using a TCP port is a simple and extensible way to manage services in a cross-platform manner, but I would like to know how safe it is and what risks I need to consider, when I rely on SIGTERM and shutdown hooks as a primary method for service shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as Java service uses ShutdownHooks wisely for orderly termination, there is no problem in sending SIGTERM to JVM process. E.g. we use SIGTERM as a primary method for initiating an application shutdown in our large high-load production system (5000+ servers running 80 different Java applications).